# Outlook custom add in change icon

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, ribbonx

Im creating a custom add in using the `yo office` command. I just want to know how i can change the icon on the outlook mail app. Ive. try everything but nothing works. [Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu0U1.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to change the icon on the ribbon. For that you need to add an icon to your web app and define it in the resources section to which you can refer in the ribbon markup:

```
<!-- Define a control that calls a JavaScript function. -->
<Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1Id1">
  <Label resid="residLabel" />
  <Tooltip resid="residToolTip" />
  <Supertip>
    <Title resid="residLabel" />
    <Description resid="residToolTip" />
  </Supertip>
  <Icon>
    <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_16x16" />
    <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
    <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_80x80" />
  </Icon>
  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>getData</FunctionName>
  </Action>
</Control>
```

The resources section from the manifest file may look like that:

```
<Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
<Resources>
```

Read more about that in the [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) article.

Comment: yes i already know that it, i literally can see the image, what i mean i the image links are working and when i try the outlook browser the icon are change and working. But on the outlook mail app ( desktop ) that icon does not change at all.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache to remove an old icon?

Comment: Yes. I already did but the issue is on the outlook browser but on outlook desktop , Check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzrBH.png

Comment: You need to clear the add-ins cache folder (and browser which is used by Outlook). If it doesn't help try to remove the add-in and then install it back.

Comment: Yes already did that. everything from clearing the cache. re install it back. restart my laptop like everything.

Comment: Try to host the add-in on the server, i.e. change the URL of your web app.

Comment: The short answer is change the name/location of your icon. I.e. from http://contso.com/image.jpg to http://contoso.com/image2.jpg That will cause Outlook to redownload and update. The long answer is that outlook doesn't clear the cache of downloaded icons, can it can be cleared manually if you delete the WEF folder from C:\Users\[UserData]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef